# youtube player api with multiple player don't refresh images

Tags: javascript, youtube

i want to use 15-20 videos each with a seekTo different to other, my problem is when videos is loaded the picture on the somes player remain black , image don't showup, my plan is to have the picture stop at "seekTo" for each and showing the image at seekTo, actually some still turning even i create pause and "setTimeout 6000", maybe some of you know this issue ?

thanks for your help
here me code for two players :

```
// Video 0 ///////////////////////
let section = {
    start: 25,
    end: 70
};
let player;
function onPlayerReady(event) {
      progressBarmove(); //load progress bar
      player.mute();
      event.target.seekTo(section.start - 4);//frame start//////////////////////////////
      player.playVideo(); 
      setTimeout(pauseVideo, 6000);
}
let timeout = null;
let timeout_2 = null;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {  

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && player.getCurrentTime() < (section.start + 2)) {
        let timerest = player.getCurrentTime();
        console.log("Current time player 0: "+ timerest);
        timeout = setTimeout(pauseVideo, (section.end - section.start) * 1000);//frame stop - le start !!////////////////////////////
    }
    else if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING)
    {
        let timerest = player.getCurrentTime();
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        console.log("clear timeout");
        console.log(("temp restant player0: "+ (section.end - timerest)) );
        if(timeout_2 !== null)
        {
            clearTimeout(timeout_2);
            console.log("clear timeout_2");
        }
        timeout_2 = setTimeout(pauseVideo, (section.end - timerest) * 1000);
        console.log(("temp restant player0: "+ (section.end - timerest)) );
        console.log("clear timeout_2 value: "+timeout_2);
        console.log("clear timeout value: "+timeout);
    }
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
        let timerest = player.getCurrentTime();
        console.log("Current time player 0: "+ timerest);
    }
}
function pauseVideo() {
    player.seekTo(section.start);//frame start    
    player.playVideo();  
    setTimeout(player.pauseVideo(),  1000);
    player.unMute();
}
///-------------------------------------------------------------------------------///

// Video 1 ///////////////////////
let section1 = {
    start: 74,
    end: 160
};
let player1;
function onPlayerReady1(event) {
      player1.mute();
      event.target.seekTo(section1.start - 4);//frame start//////////////////////////////
      player1.playVideo();
      setTimeout(pauseVideo1, 6000);      
}
let timeout1 = null;
let timeout1_2 = null;
function onPlayerStateChange1(event) {  

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && player1.getCurrentTime() < (section1.start + 2)) {
        let timerest = player1.getCurrentTime();
        console.log("Current time player 1: "+ timerest);
        timeout1 = setTimeout(pauseVideo1, (section1.end - section1.start) * 1000);//frame stop - le start !!////////////////////////////
    }
    else if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING)
    {
        let timerest = player1.getCurrentTime();
        clearTimeout(timeout1);
        console.log("clear timeout1");
        console.log(("temp restant player1: "+ (section1.end - timerest)) );
        if(timeout1_2 !== null)
        {
            clearTimeout(timeout1_2);
            console.log("clear timeout1_2");
        }
        timeout1_2 = setTimeout(pauseVideo1, (section1.end - timerest) * 1000);
        console.log(("temp restant player1: "+ (section1.end - timerest)) );
        console.log("clear timeout1_2 value: "+timeout1_2);
        console.log("clear timeout1 value: "+timeout1);
    }
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
        let timerest = player1.getCurrentTime();
        console.log("Current time player 1: "+ timerest);
    }
}
function pauseVideo1() {
    player1.seekTo(section1.start);//frame start    
    player1.playVideo();  
    setTimeout(player1.pauseVideo(),  1000);
    player1.unMute(); 
}



////////////////////////////
///and when ready //////////
////////////////////////////



//Render Video
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {    
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '360',
        width: '350',
        videoId: 'n_H_YMPlEkY',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
    player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
        height: '360',
        width: '350',
        videoId: 'n_H_YMPlEkY',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady1,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange1
        }
    });
}
let tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
let firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Comment: can you use https://jsfiddle.net/ for create a [mcve]?

Comment: sure is the link,   https://jsfiddle.net/h6rn5jaz/    the html page you see is loaded into a <object> html on the main.html page

Comment: on jsfiddle the player load correctly..

Comment: For loading content into main page , i use <object> , <iframe> don't work and i don't realy know why.

Comment: thanks for add the jsfiddle sample. It has more visibility if you add your jsfiddle link in your question. Also, I've arranged your code a bit for reduce the errors shown in the console - see [jsfiddle forked sample](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSO2021/0osy1zxn/)

Comment: That being said, I'm not quite sure what do you mean by: `my plan is to have the picture stop at "seekTo" for each` = the iframes loaded are stopped at the given time you set with `seekTo`. By this, do you mean that you want to the iframe don't load afterwards? - please, press [edit] and clarify about this in your question. Also, I've edited the jsfiddle example for reduce errors in the console. Please, check it out and let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and the fix of many error on console, also i have edited the post to clarify my problem. Tanks again !

Comment: with the changes I've made I get the images in all the iframes. Can you check again and let me know for post it as an answer?

Comment: OK the problem persist but I update the jsfiddle this  night and I tel you when is ready

Comment: here the updated jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/isoparme/xjct9ake/4/
So you see comment and main page paste into comment, i try to explain:
the index.html load => next client can select a page to load into a <object> via javascript addeventlistener into the index.html , i thing the problem is that, i try with a <iframe> but youtube simply don't appear... any idea ? thanks for your help again!